# How to unmount based on volume type using Python GIO library

Tags: python, gio

I am trying to mimic the behaviour of shell command `gio mount` which unmounts all gphoto2 cameras

```
gio mount -s gphoto2
```

How to detect if volume is `gphoto2`? I tried getting volume type but there doesn't seem to be variable that holds it,

```
from gi.repository import Gio, GObject

def main():
    mo = Gio.MountOperation()
    mo.set_anonymous(True)

    vl = Gio.VolumeMonitor.get()

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    for v in vl.get_mounts():
        print(dir(v))
        print(v.get_name(), v.get_uuid(), v.g_type_instance, v.get_drive(),
              v.get_volume(),
              v.get_root(),
              v.get_drive(),
              v.get_sort_key(),
              v.get_uuid())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the root of the mount (https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GMount.html#g-mount-get-root) and check its URI scheme (https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-has-uri-scheme). If the scheme is `gphoto2`, you can unmount it.

See the [C implementation of `gio mount -s`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/341c58b44a698c68ba96639636fd02e54cbaddd7/gio/gio-tool-mount.c#L922).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out `if v.get_root().has_uri_scheme("gphoto2"):  print("yes")`